# Using subprocess.call to execute python file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, subprocess

I am using `subprocess.call` in order to execute another python file. Considering that the script that will be called will never terminate the execution as it's inside an infinite loop, how can I make it possible for the original script to continue the execution after the subprocess call ?

Example: 
I have script1.py which does some calculations and then calls script2.py using `subprocess.call(["python", "script2.py"])`, since it's inside an infinite loop the script1 gets stuck on execution, is there another way to run the file other than using subprocess module ?

Comment: Can you just shove the response in a future or on a second thread or something like that and forget about it?

Comment: There is no need to use `subprocess` for this. Have `script1.py` import `script2` and call its main function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`subprocess.call(["python", "script2.py"])` waits for the sub-process to finish.

Just use [`Popen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) instead:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(["python", "script2.py"])
```

You can later do `proc.poll()` to see whether it is finished or not, or `proc.wait()` to wait for it to finish (as `call` does), or just forget about it and do other things instead.

BTW, you might want to ensure that the same `python` is called, and that the OS can find it, by using [`sys.executable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.executable) instead of just `"python"`:

```
subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, "script2.py"])
```